# izpack java installer, shortcut with noShow still shows the batch window

Tags: java, batch-file, installation, izpack

Hi I am using izPack to create a windows java installer. I use the following to create a shortcut:

```
<shortcut
    name = "ApplicationName"
    target = "$INSTALL_PATH\start.bat"
    commandLine = ""
    workingDirectory= "$INSTALL_PATH"
    description="Application Desc"
    iconFile="$INSTALL_PATH\app.ico"
    iconIndex="0"
    initialState="noShow"
    programGroup="yes"
    desktop="yes"
    applications="no"
    startMenu="no"
    startup="no"/>
```

When I click on the created shortcut it executes the `start.bat` script, but the window does not hide. Thus I have two windows open...

My `start.bat` contains basically the following:

```
...
java -cp %CLASSPATH% com.package.Application >NUL 2>&1
```

It works with a second application that does not open a window and runs with `javaw`.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I got it right from your description, but have you tried to use javaw instead of java inside the bat itself? If yes, is that solution not what you want?
It also seems this is the recommandation for a [related question](http://old.nabble.com/Shortcut-problems-with-IzPack-4.2-td21924325.html).

Comment: Yes, actually that was the solution. I just had it running without javaw before, or I thought it should work without javaw... thanks for the answer anyway!